# Vector Autoregressive Models with Non Stationary Variables

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, unit-root, stationarity

I am beginning to study VAR models, and I have a simple question.

- If I have three variables and one of them is nonstationary, can I estimate a standard VAR model? If not, what should I do?

Comment: No you cannot. If only one series is unit root non-stationary you should remove the unit root by first (or second) differencing the non-stationary series. Then continue the analysis using the the differenced series.

Comment: thanks. I Got it. In this case I would run the VAR and interprets the beta parameter as a function of different variable. The interpretation for the impulse response function would take place in the same way? Right?

Comment: Yes. You would continue the analysis as you would if all three would have been stationary in levels. See the notes by Eric Zivot: http://www.eco.uc3m.es/~jgonzalo/teaching/timeseriesma/zivotvarnotes-reading.pdf. Page 11-12 discuss exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry. It was actually p. 15 - combination of I(0) and I(1) variables. The link is here: http://www.eco.uc3m.es/~jgonzalo/teaching/timeseriesma/zivotvarnotes-reading.pdf